# Как правильно написать цикл

Tags: python, python-3.x, циклы

Есть код:

```
x = ['1','2','3']

for i in x:
    print(i)
    y = ['a', 'b', 'c']
    for elem in y:
          print(elem)
```

На выходе имеем:

```
1
a
b
c
2
a
b
c
3
a
b
c

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Как сделать так, чтобы на выходе получилось:

```
1 a 2 b 3 c

Process finished with exit code 0
```

?

Answer (score 2):

Используйте `zip`, чтобы объединять попарно элементы:

```
x = ['1','2','3']
y = ['a', 'b', 'c']

for i, j in zip(x, y):
    print(i, j, end=' ')

print()
```

Тот же результат, но в одну строку:

```
print(' '.join(f'{i} {j}' for i, j in zip(x, y)))
```